# Use IF / ELSE IF on STORED PROCEDURE in Sql Server 2005

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have problem with this **STORED PROCEDURE** in Sql Server.

Any value entered as a **parameter** extracts data with parameter 'S'.

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

My code below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxxx](@StartDate VARCHAR(10),@EndDate VARCHAR(10),@Parameter CHAR(1)) 
AS
IF @Parameter='S'
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM doTable_S

END

ELSE IF @Parameter='A'
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM doTable_A
END
```

**#EDIT01**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxxx](@StartDate VARCHAR(10),@EndDate VARCHAR(10),@Parameter CHAR(1)) 
AS
BEGIN
IF @Parameter='S'
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM doTable_S

END

ELSE IF @Parameter='A'
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM doTable_A
END
END
```

Comment: Isn't there a `BEGIN` missing after the `AS`? And an `END` at the end?

Comment: @OcasoProtalTahks but I don't ahve change in output, please see **#EDIT01** in my first question

Comment: Apparently you always pass `'S'` for the parameter, or this is not the actual code.

Comment: @GSerg the code is actual ... and in the parameter I pass 'A' value but in output I have all value of doTable_S